# Elements of a group (basic idea)

Tags: group-theory

I am just starting to look at group theory and struggling with how abstract it is. This may seem very basic but say we have a group, the integers under addition, would all he elements of the group be all the results from all the possible ways to add the integers? i.e. 1+1=2 so 2 is an element? but then there are going to be loads of repeated elements? are the repeated elements included in the group or do they only appear once?

Comment: What do you mean "repeated elements"? Do you mean how $1+3$ and $2+2$ are the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group is a set of elements, together with an operation which takes any two elements from the set and gives you a third element from the set. This set and this operation must satisfy some niceness conditions (associativity, identity and inverse), and that's it.

It is true that for any group, if you take all the different possible ways to combine two elements together using the operation, then as a result you get all the different possible elements of the group, and it's true that each element of the group may appear multiple times in this manner. But that is secondary. The group is defined as a set and an operation, not as the set you get as a result of applying the operation.

What you *do* have in group theory, which might look like what you're doing, is the concept of generators. Given a group $G$ and an operation $*$, you can take a subset of the elements (say, for instance, $\{g_1, g_2, g_3\}$), and look at what you get if you combine them in all possible ways using the operation (in this case $g_1*g_1, g_1*g_2, g_1*g_3, \ldots$, as well as using *those* elements again, so you get things like $g_1*g_1*g_2$, and so on).

If you take every element you got as a result of this, and add to that the inverse of any of those elements and the identity element, you get the *subgroup generated by $g_1, g_2, g_3$*, commonly denoted $\langle g_1, g_2, g_3\rangle$. If you happen to get the entire group this way, then we say that $G$ is generated by $g_1, g_2, g_3$. In this case, you will often get repeats, yes, but again that doesn't matter. How many times an element appears here is irrelevant. Only whether it appears at all matters.

For the group $(\Bbb Z, +)$, we have that $\langle 1\rangle$ is the entire group, because every integer is the result of ading $1$ to itself some finite number of times, possibly with a negative sign. This is a special type of group (may be generated using only a single element), called a *cyclic* group. Most groups need more than one generator if you want to reach the whole group.

Answer (score 0):

The elements only appear once in the set, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots \}$. Of course, we have infinitely many ways to represent an element, e.g., $0=1-1=2-2=\cdots$.